# Codenameone: Is there a way how to redirect user from browser to app

Tags: codenameone

Lets say if I put this url to browser `android://test?par1=xxx&par2=yyy` it will trigger redirect to application.

You can do this with `intend-filter` and you can receive `par1` and `par2` via `Activity` function `getIntend().getDate()`

It is possible in Codename One to do this behavior?

Especially, how to recieve `par1` nad `par2` from the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppArg", ""); to get this data